# Astra theme for Wordpress - related products do not respect responsibility in Woocommerce product detail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming, wordpress-theme-astra

Related products at Woocommerce product detail on some mobile phones do not respect responsibity, so it shows 4 very thin columns. Altough only 1 column is set at settings.

https://www.nabytek-natali.cz/p/calounena-postel-boxspring-bolero/

Any idea?

Thanks